# JSON custom serializer

Tags: python, django, json, serialization, django-models

I need to serialize django models to json format so I wrote custom methods for full and short versions (for optimization of listings), e.g.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    def serialize_full(self):
        return {
            'title': self.title,
            'absolute_url': self.get_absolute_url(),
            'content': self.content, 
            ...  # many heavy fields 
        }

    def serialize_short(self):        
        return {
            'title': self.title,
            'absolute_url': self.get_absolute_url(),
        }
```

Then I redefined default encoder

```
class JSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, QuerySet):
            return [o.serialize_short() for o in obj]
        if isinstance(obj, models.Model):
            return obj.serialize_full()
        return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

*This is a shorter version of my code in order to show the main idea.

But this way I can't redefine serialization of `list` (it's hardcoded in python `json` module).
Now `list` of articles is serialized by `serialize_full`, not `serialize_short` method as I'd like.